# Synchronous demodulation

Tags: demodulation

In the analog switch-based synchronous demodulation of a signal, say 1 MHz, how does the turn-on and turn-off time of the switch impact the demodulated and filtered DC output (demodulation here is performed to get the phase shift)?

What will will be acceptable t<sub>ON</sub> and t<sub>OFF</sub> for the switches? For example, the CD4066 has t<sub>ON</sub> and t<sub>OFF</sub> in the range of 200 ns, while a JFET switch like the LF1333 has an even larger t<sub>ON</sub> of 500 ns, and a smaller turn-off. What are the criteria for selecting a switch considering a 1 MHz signal input?

The input signal is +/-100 mV. Will there be a rapid transition at the output with a supply voltage of +/-5 V, considering the sample swing of the input signal?

Details: In switch-based synchronous demodulation the analog switch act as multiplier fed with a square wave as a LO signal. My question is: does the delay time (for turn-on and turn-off) in the switch affect the multiplier operation, and how can I quantify it with respect to the time constant of the low-pass filter used at the output of the multiplier?

Because if there is a delay, my assumption is that a different part of the input signal will be sampled at the low-pass filter rather than the intended one, which may produce errors in phase and quadrature output.

The feed-through effect @ 1 MHz switching is worse. The method of testing: I grounded the input pin and probed the output pin with logic input, and found around 130 mV peak-to-peak, even though a 1 nF cap to ground at the output absorbs the feed-through charge.

This makes me wonder how come there are so many implementations in scholarly articles mentioning this scheme of demodulation, even for precise instrumentation. Am I doing something utterly wrong?

Update 10/02/2024:
As members pointed out faster switches are better,from practical point of view that closes this issue,but I thought of discussing about how much worse(on and off delay)is better for particular frequency of signal and accuracy of the application. Though it will take some effort analytically that will be worth while exercise I am planning to do.

Comment: Why are you using a slow switch from half a century ago? Plenty of much faster switches around...

Comment: You might consider substituting the HC version (74HC4066). Max Vdd is only 6V, but that should still accommodate a 100mV analog signal. Spec'd to 30 MHz. Even Cd4066B seems fast enough for 1MHz.

Comment: @johnDoty yeah much faster TTL switches  are available,but my input is centred around ground any DC shift give to get it compatible with TTL like fst3253 will compromise the detection process making it depend on the stability of DC bias.please suggest some part numbers.

Comment: @glen_geek yeah ton and toff of around 20 ns at +/-5v supply but how to quantify this effect on the demodulation process considering out of 500ns postive cycle of input signal already 40ns of information is lost on switching delay..am i missing anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the purpose of bot here...does it understand the language we spoke..leave alone the abstract language used in electronic concepts.

Comment: Okay ..I will detail it as much as i can..in switch based synchronous demodulation the analog switch act as multiplier fed with a square wave as a LO signal.my question is does the delay time (for turn on and turn off) in switch affect the multiplier operation and how can I quantify it with respect to the time constant of the low pass filter used at the output of the multiplier.because if there is a delay my assumption is different part of the input signal will be sampled at the low pass filter rather than the intended one which may produce erroneous in phase and quadrature output

Comment: If this is the case,I will look at analog mixers may be Gilbert cell core or passive mixers for this application.

Comment: To the extent that in-phase and quadrature paths (and switches) are matched, any "delay" should be similar in those two channels. When I've pushed a I&Q sampler past its speed spec, I've not noticed timing errors between in-phase and quadrature outputs. But my app was followed by long time constant filters. I'd do some testing if demodulator output pushed bandwidth limits set by Nyquist.

Comment: What's ground? A common technique in mixed signal design is to refer the analog signals to a "virtual" ground between the supply rails. That's very helpful in cases like this, where single supply switches have much better performance than split supply switches.

Comment: @JohnDoty ground here is virtual ground between +/-5V

Comment: @glen_geek yes if the delay is deterministic and symmetrical on both sides it suffices,although it will be more use to me if you specify bit more of the setup you are using.may be frequency and the switch type used.

Comment: Why 10V rail-rail for 200 mV p-p signals? For fast switches, you want to be below 5V.

Comment: @johnDoty Larger the supply voltage is an advantage for switch as it decrease the channel resistance during tON .besides +/5v supply is for other block in the system,so used the same.Yes there are fast TTL switches with 5ns delay,as I already mentioned my application is bipolar.so trying to DC bias the switch input will make the demodulation process depend on the stability of the bias,but since my input is only +/200mV at the max I'm not quite sure whether I can use TTL switch as it have max rating -0.5V below ground,but there will be no guarantee for performance

Comment: What's this "DC bias" stuff? Use a virtual ground for your analog portion, refer *all* analog signals to that, make it different from your logic ground.

Comment: High voltage leads to large charge injection, which you are complaining about.

Comment: If you search for fast, low resistance CMOS switches, you find things like https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG749.pdf Lots of similar things available these days. TTL and 4000 series are from the last century.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151418/discussion-between-dhuwarkesh-and-john-doty).

Answer (score 3):

You can regard slow switching of the demodulation switches as an effective low pass filter on the signal you are trying to sample.

Qualitatively, consider the switching aperture window as the impulse response of the filter. This will be convolved with the input signal. Take the Fourrier transform of that window. That's the sort of shape and frequency of the filter you will get.

Quantitatively, it's much more difficult. The 'switching time' of these analogue switches tends to be rated by when a step signal is nearly finished, rather than by how they attenuate a signal through the switching region. It's not consistent with their use as demodulators. You would need to build and measure, either a good simulation, or real hardware, ideally both, to see exactly what you were going to get.

But generally, a faster switch will get you more bandwidth and less time error.

I'm not sure what your last paragraph is asking. It sounds like you're worried about feedthough from the switch control to the signal. Different switches will have different levels of this. If it's not specified in the data sheet, then it's probably worse than one that is.

Comment: Thank you.In last paragraph I meant to ask whether the level of input signal have an effect on rise time,+/-100mv compared to +/-1 v signal.i dont think it is

Comment: @dhuwarkesh With an analogue switch, I would expect the rise time to be broadly independent of signal amplitude for small amplitudes. The switch resistance does change with signal level, but tends to be quite flat over the middle 1/3rd (for pretty much all of the CMOS switches I've seen).

Comment: If this is the case..Is analog mixer either passive or active is the way to go for precision application?or if I can get a switch with symmetrical Ton and Toff in that it eases  calculation,because for some jfet analog switches Ton and Toff are different.

Comment: by analog i mean a Gilbert cell multiplier or a diode ring,because  above discussed method can also be considered as quasi-analog.

Answer (score 0):

> the CD4066 has tON and tOFF in the range of 200 ns

That's the worst-case spec. They perform much better these days, thanks to the dialed-in manufacturing process control. These specs were based on fairly poor process control in the 70s when the series was standardized. Even back then the performance could be much better if you just selected for the parts from the fast process corner.

Today, you've got to actually try what they do. TI's CD4000 manufactured in the last few years seem to perform best around 12V, and they are much faster than the worst-case. I could probably select a CD4066 to switch in 20ns without much trouble! I haven't checked the CD4016 for speed yet.

If you're buying logic parts for projects, getting recent TI-made 4000-series parts is really worth it, they handily outperform old stock. Same goes for any other "old" CMOS part like 74HC series.

> Details: In switch-based synchronous demodulation the analog switch act as multiplier fed with a square wave as a LO signal. My question is: does the delay time (for turn-on and turn-off) in the switch affect the multiplier operation

It does. How exactly it does depends on the exact behavior of the switch, so IMHO you just have to measure it. And you need a spec for what performance you need in your application to begin with, without even looking at any parts. Then you need to decide how much labor you're willing to put into selecting parts (as in: buying many, selecting few that work much better than guaranteed specs), and what sort of support circuitry you're willing to add.

> if there is a delay, my assumption is that a different part of the input signal will be sampled at the low-pass filter rather than the intended one, which may produce errors in phase and quadrature output.

When it comes to pure delay, if you're running the switch at a fixed frequency it's a non-issue. Just phase-shift the clock edges appropriately to null out the delay. You'd typically leave one switch on each chip to act as a feedback source, and run the adjustable delays based on what that feedback switch is doing. This compensates for aging, temperature dependence, and so on.

There are many ways of getting a variable delay based on a control voltage. With feedback, the linearity of the delay vs control voltage is not a big concern. An RC filter working with a small amplitude square wave signal riding on a DC offset is a nice adjustable delay when the capacitor is a high-K ceramic like Y5V. A varicap can do that job too, but usually they need much higher bias voltages. A 6V-rated Y5V part can change capacitance over an order of magnitude between 0 and 6V of bias.

The turn-on and turn-off delay is a good spec to start with, but it doesn't nearly paint the whole picture. What you really need to look at is measured channel resistance vs. time as the switch is switching, measured at various input voltages, and over the temperature range of interest. That's where the details come out. Armed with the measurements you can make a SPICE model that captures the behavior, and play with it in SPICE, making distortion measurement etc. It's preferable to avoid SPICE though if you can.

> The feed-through effect @ 1 MHz switching is worse. The method of testing: I grounded the input pin and probed the output pin with logic input, and found around 130 mV peak-to-peak, even though a 1 nF cap to ground at the output absorbs the feed-through charge.

Feed-through is constant if you operate the switch at a fixed voltage, i.e. into the virtual ground node of an op-amp. That's one of the tricks to minimize the non-ideal behavior of CMOS switches. You can control (fine-tune) the VCC voltage of the switch to stabilize the feedthrough amplitude or RMS value or whatever you care about keeping constant in your application.

A lot of the questions you ask can be summarized to "how to work around nonidealities of analog components" - there's a lot to know in that field. And a lot can be done with closed-loop feedback.

> This makes me wonder how come there are so many implementations in scholarly articles mentioning this scheme of demodulation, even for precise instrumentation

It works well in practice. You have to get to measure system performance, and not only focus on single specifications like feedthrough. Then you may observe how the system architecture can get rid of the negative effects of the nonidealities.

Comment: Yes,charge injection can be mitigated or at least made repeatable.yes I quoted the worst case delay,specs are much better depending on use case. As the switched signal is very small compared to the supply and also at mid rail of the switch,the channel resistance variation is minimum. i will draw out a scheme for implementing the delay with feedback and update. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this design, part of the [TESS](https://tess.mit.edu/) [focal plane electronics](https://github.com/TESScience/FPE/blob/FPE-7.0/Releases/FPE-7.0-revA/FPE.pdf).

[image]

This is a "correlated double sampling" circuit for CCD video, an elaboration on the synchronous detection idea.

Employing a single 5V supply allowed me to choose a 20 ns 10 ohm switch (MAX4594). Even better switches are available in 2024. V0, the virtual ground, is 3V.

Comment: thankyou very much.i will look at it.